# How to setup and publish first push in github?

Tags: git, github, git-push

My client added me into his private repository in Github with push authority. I tried to do my first commit and I followed [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) guide for setup my first commit. But I found error while pushing my commit.

What I do is :

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin remote https://github.com/username/rep.git
git remote -v
git push origin master
```

Everything goes perfectly but last line gave me following error.

```
C:\wamp64\www\res>git push origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/rep.git/' not found
```

Comment: Work through the debugging steps listed in the [GitHub documentation here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/) and get back if you still can't resolve the issue

Comment: Did you create the repository on github before?

Comment: My client has created a repository and added some files too. And I have no issues cloning the repository, and also I tried documentation. It doesn't help, however I used desktop app and It works fine. but I am concern about command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: there is no repository at `https://github.com/username/rep.git/`

It doesn't look like your client created the repository. Maybe they just invited you into their private organization?
Either way, the repository needs to be created in the Github interface before you can push to it.

Also note that the command to add your remote should be:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/rep.git`

Comment: My client has created the repository and added few files too. What I want is to add all remaining files I have.